# How to show the saved number when I open the app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have this code to save the times i clicked on the imageview but every time I open the App the first number I see is 0, but I want to see the "highscore" instantly.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView megg;
int counter = 0;
int readhighscore;
private TextView mnumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));



    megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
    megg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            readhighscore = counter;
            mnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
            mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));



        }

    });

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    counter = prefs.getInt("highscore", readhighscore);


}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("highscore", readhighscore);

    editor.commit();

}
}
```

Comment: Try putting `mnumber.setText` after you actually  get the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView megg;
    int counter = 0;
    int readhighscore;
    private TextView mnumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
        mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));



        megg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.egg);
        megg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                readhighscore = counter;
                mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));



            }

        });

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        counter = prefs.getInt("highscore", readhighscore);


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("highscore", readhighscore);

        editor.commit();

    }
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        counter = prefs.getInt("highscore", readhighscore);
        readhighscore = counter;
        mnumber.setText(Integer.toString(readhighscore));
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution  :

Saving :

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("highscore", storedPreference); 
    editor.apply();
```

Retrieving :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("highscore", 0); // this value you can show in your UI.
```

In your activity onCreate()

```
if(preferences.contains("highscore)){
 SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
 int storedPreference = preferences.getInt("highscore", 0);
number.setText(storedPreference+"");
}
```

Comment: I get this Error message:Error:(62, 81) error: cannot find symbol variable Context

Comment: put this / YourActivirty.this instead of context

Answer (score 0):

Here you are looking up the textview "mnumber" two times first time before megg's click block and second time inside megg's onclick event block. I think you must avoid the code "mnumber=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);" from second block.